# Does WebRequest.Create method actually calls a url?

Tags: c#, webrequest

One of my colleague suggested me WebRequest.Create actually sends a web request to the specified url and I don't have to use asynchronous web request in order to avoid waiting.

Is this true?

How ever I don't agree with him and when I showed him the documentation but he said that he has been calling WebRequest.Create to send requests.

I'm not sure if this is true as i don't have deep knowledge of .net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, calls to `GetResponse()` on the created `WebRequest` is what actually issues the request.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx):

> The GetResponse method sends a request to an Internet resource and returns a WebResponse instance.

Answer (score 1):

That is not true. It just initializes a new request.

You need to call `GetResponse()` to actually make the call.